# How to Copy the content from second latest folder to another one

Tags: powershell, file-copying

I'm trying to find the second latest folder (in terms of creation date) and would like to copy its contents to another folder.

Here is the code:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\server\parent_folder\folder" | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -Descending | select -first 1

Copy-Item -path "\\server\parent_folder1\folder" -Destination "\\server\parent_folder2\folder" -recursive
```

The first code only shows the latest folder. But, after replacing "1" with "2" at the end, it gives me both latest and second latest folder,  but I only want it to return the later one.

Next line of code is to copy its content to another folder.

How do I select only one folder (second latest) and copy its contents?

Answer (score 0):

You can `-Skip` over items too (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6):

```
Get-ChildItem "\server\parent_folder\folder" | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -Descending | select -skip 1 -first 1
```